# TCP versions and AIMD

Tags: networking, tcp

When we talk about TCP we often talk about Additive Increase Multiplicative Decrease.

In particular we suggest that we decrease the Congestion Window Size by a factor of 2 on packet loss. However am I right in thinking that there are in fact multiple approaches?

In TCP-Tahoe we actually don't do AIMD at all. When we time-out or a triple dup-ack occurs, the CWND is set to 1, and slow-start begins again (Note this is not a multiplicative decrease).

In TCP-Reno, we set CWND := CWND/2 on a triple dup-ack, and CWND := 1 on a timeout. (Note only the first instance is a multiplicative decrease)

This division of CWND by two is part of a process referred to as fast-recovery, this is where (and only where) AIMD is implemented.

Is the above correct? Could you therefore identify whether a TCP version was Tahoe or Reno from the sawtooth? Would it be correct to state that Tahoe does not do AIMD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've said is correct, let me reexplain it with details:

## Slow Start

Any TCP congestion control algorithm starts from congestion window size `cwnd = 1` MSS (**Maximum Segment Size** as congestion window size is scaled by bytes) then it starts an additive increase according to the number of received acknowledgements until it reaches the slow start threshold value **ssthresh** that's the intial advertised window size.

So, let's suppose `ssthresh = 8`. TCP starts sending the first segment according to `cwnd = 1` if an acknowledgement is received cwnd is additively increased by the number of acknowledgements received according to the formula `cwnd = cwnd + MSS` (this means that the congestion window size is increased by 1 segment).

when `cwnd >= ssthresh` then each time an ACK is received, increment cwnd as follows: `cwnd = cwnd + MSS(MSS/ cwnd)` (don't forget that cwnd is in bytes). So cwnd is increased by one segment (=MSS bytes) only if all segments have been acknowledged, e.g.:

let's suppose last cwnd was 8.

`cwnd = 8 + 1 * ( 1 / 8)` and this is repeated 8 times (because all segments have been acknowledged). So after adding `1 / 8` to cwnd 8 times, the result is 1 MSS added to the last known cwnd which is 8 i.e. new cwnd is 9.
[image: Figure 1 - Slow Start]

**Slow Start Algorithm**

```
If cwnd < ssthresh then
    Each time an Ack is received:
    cwnd = cwnd + MSS
else /* cwnd >= ssthresh */
    Each time an Ack is received :
    cwnd = cwnd + MSS. MSS / cwnd
endif
```

## [Response to Congestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion-avoidance_algorithm#TCP_Tahoe_and_Reno)

There is 2 ways to detect loss:

1. TCP retransmission timer has a timeout
2. Receipt of duplicate ACK

### TCP Reno

- Case 1: Timer Timeout

  Reno drops to cwnd to 1 then reinitialize a slow start with ssthresh = last_cwnd / 2.
- Case 2: 3 Duplicate Acknowledgemnts
  Reno do:

  1. sshresh = cwnd /2
  2. cwnd = cwnd / 2
  3. Enters Fast Retransmission state:  retransmits the missing packet that was signaled by three duplicate ACKs, and waits for an acknowledgment of the entire transmit window before returning to congestion avoidance.

### TCP Tahoe

For both cases, Tahoe always drops cwnd to 1 then reinitialize a slow start with ssthresh = last_cwnd / 2.

> Could you therefore identify whether a TCP version was Tahoe or Reno
>   from the sawtooth?

TCP congestion algorithms are always implement in the OS level. Windows and Linux implements the following algorithms (according to [this paper](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1208&context=cseconfwork)):
[image: Figure 2 - Congestion Algorithms on Windows and Linux]

> Would it be correct to state that Tahoe does not do AIMD?

Tahoe only implements Additive Increase and doesn't implement Multiplicative Decrease. Reno implements them both.